# Have Error While uploading App in one mobile Markt

Tags: javascript, java, android, error-handling

hey guys i have error when uploading my Andriod game to 1 mobile markt 
it says that 
‫Upload failed Build number cannot be empty

i used BuildBox to make it and Save it as .APK with Android studio

Comment: You have to have a build number specified in your build.gradle file

Comment: i cant found this file in my app pr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Manifest File, you must have kept the `android:versionCode` or `android:versionName` as empty.

Both are compulsory & non-empty fields.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

If it is not empty then put the proper values in the manifest such that it is greater then the older version.

Comment: You mean that i have make it Empty ?

Comment: @A.Hamo : Yes by mistake, you have kept it empty i.e. in your current code `android:versionCode=""` or `android:versionName=""`
Whereas, you should not keep it empty.

Comment: @A.Hamo: Also if possible, please share the screenshot.

Comment: /*___Generated_by_IDEA___*/

package AH.Crash.sword.com;

/* This stub is only used by the IDE. It is NOT the Manifest class actually packed into the APK */
public final class Manifest {
}    this what is in the minefast

Comment: @A.Hamo: Bro you are looking at the wrong Manifest file.
There is 1 more Manifest file named as : "AndroidManifest.xml".
Try to open that file & upload the screenshot.

Comment: Im sorry Im a Beginar :) nowi had the right one what should ichange?

Comment: bro You are My here <3 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="AH.Crash.sword.com"
      android:versionCode="123456789"
      android:versionName="1.0">
here the same code you now i have to change this nubms to empty ?

Comment: @A.Hamo : No, don't change it to empty.
Please write a proper version code.

"123456789", this is wrong, & therefore the market is giving error.

If your versionName is 1.0 then how can versionCode be 123456789.
It should be: `android:versionCode="1"`

Comment: Look at this now  ihave change it like what you said http://i.imgur.com/V2HFoe4.png

Comment: @A.Hamo : Please sync your grade, extract apk & again try to upload.